# Windows Terminal, how to save split pane layout?

Tags: terminal, panel, windows-terminal

Is there a way I can save current split panel layout and profile for each panel so I don't need to split and open profile one by one again?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Comment: Windows terminal is a tools for developers, no different than VSCode.

Comment: Visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Windows Terminal is not one of of those tools *"used primarily for programming"*, any more than Microsoft Word is.

Comment: I use Windows Terminal on the daily to launch my app, run tests and make api calls against that app as I prefer the CLI, to compare it to Word is unjustified.

Answer (score 6):

This feature does not yet exist as part of Windows Terminal.

However, this feature was suggested, and the suggestion has been accepted and is being tracked in the Windows Terminal github issues backlog:
https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/3759

### Work-around:

You can call windows terminal (wt) from the command line and specify starting directories, splits, tabs, profiles, etc.

For example, run this from command line and it will open up 2 Windows Terminal tabs, the first tab will be a split layout with PowerShell profile + your default profile, and the other tab will use the Ubuntu WSL profile:

`wt -d "C:\Windows\System32" -p "PowerShell"; sp -V -d "%USERPROFILE%"; nt -p "Ubuntu" --title "wsl" --tabColor "#FF0000"`

Better yet, set this command as the file location for a *shortcut* on your desktop and you can just double click the shortcut to open your favorite Windows Terminal configuration.

See more wt command line options here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/command-line-arguments?tabs=windows